# Should I move some Properties into a Model?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM light and I have a View Model but I am not sure if I should move some of the properties out as I got quite a few on them now.

Eventhough they are simple properties for the most part,my view model is kinda getting long(437 lines of properites)

I am wondering if it would make some sense to move out some of the properties out into a model, in a sense making it easier to find the more important properties.

I have 5 controls on my wp7 view.

5 properties for IsEnabled (if location service is turned off then all properties are disabled)l

6 properties to store the values that the user selects

3 relay commands.

1 property to hide/show a control based on what is selected.

I am still working on the page so there probably will be more in the end.

I am wondering if I should take out the 6 properties that would store the information from the user and make it into a model.

Then just have stuff like relayCommands, Visablity, Enabled stuff in the ViewModel and have one property that of course has my Model class.

Answer (score 0):

Having lean view models are always a good thing. It makes it easier to manage and understand for other developers (or yourself) later on.

Pulling your domain specific data into models is always a good thing. Say you wanted to reference that user in a different view later on - with everything piled into your view model, you'd have to replicate a lot of code every time you make a new view model. Not good.

If you pull said user into it's own domain model object, then you could simply reference the user with a single line of code (and easily access its properties through setters and getters.

Remember, MVVM stands for model, view, viewmodel, and without the models, you're stuck with potentially almost chaotic code and lots of replication. Replication of code leads to human errors while copying and a ton of other headaches.

---

now that's the general idea. I understand you're asking about how you should manage your "temporary" properties (which the users fills in), and I have to say the same rules apply here as above. Having more than a few models aren't a bad thing at all (if working in an enterprise environment has taught me anything, it's not being afraid of splitting up code into manageable sizes).

Another approach you could use is creating a parent class for your view model to inherit from. Put any "i'll need these for all my views" properties here, and the specific information is left in the view model inheriting the superclass.

A third thing I noticed is that you have an "isEnabled" property for each of your controls. If you have an "all or nothing" scenario, like you portray, you only need one. Bind that property up to the visibility of all your elements, and ease your visibility management sixfold =)

Hope this cleared a few things up! =)

Comment: Yes it is all or nothing. That is a good idea to just have one property for it. For some reason I thought they all need their own but since it is all or nothing. I am unclear would you for example put the isEnabled in a Model or keep that in the View? It only has a getter(checks to see if location service is on or off). Same with Visablity

Comment: I would keep any control specific info in the view model, as it is view specific. Stuff you can view as "information" - stuff you might want to push to a server or persist in storage, THAT's the stuff you put into models. Stuff you might want to send to another view - THAT's the stuff you put into models.

Best of luck!

Comment: Ok if I do this though, I would have a property in the Model that gets some information on the server and based on that information a controls should be hidden or shown. If I have the code that shows/hides the control in the VIEWMODEL how does that work? Do I need to do a messenger or something to tell that it needs to be hidden for instance?

Comment: I also was thinking could you show me a example of having 2 ViewModels in a single view. I been only been doing 1 to 1 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is for the view should be in your viewModel. Ideally you would not want to update your model just because your view required too. Any such things would go into the ViewModel. 
As suggested above you could break up the view models. There need not be a one-to-one mapping of views to view models. A view can be composed of many view models.

By *437 lines of properties* do you mean to say that you have 437 properties? If that is the case that is way too much for your view in itself and I would reconsider breaking up your views into more simpler ones for usability.

[Here](http://rahulpnath.com/blog/mvvm-a-windows-phone-scenario/) are a couple of common scenarios that we normally come across while using MVVM